# Scraping multiple websites at once using Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, web-scraping, python-requests

I have an Excel file with 1000 websites.

For each separate website, I want to create a new Excel file that contains the link and post title of each post on the website.

I have done the Excel extraction and I have the list of websites in a DataFrame.

Now I want to know if there is a possibility to scrape the information from all the websites.

This is what I have so far.

```
def scrape_multiple_websites(websites, link_selector, title_selector):
     """
     Function to scrape multiple websites at once
     """
     all_website_posts = {}

     for website_url in websites:
        posts = scrape_posts(website_url, link_selector, title_selector)
        all_website_posts[website_url] = posts

     return all_website_posts

def scrape_posts(url, link_selector, title_selector):
    """
    Function to scrape posts from a website
    """
    all_posts = []

    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

       post_elements = soup.select(link_selector)

       for post_element in post_elements:
          post_link = post_element['href'] if 'href' in post_element.attrs else post_element.text
          post_title = post_element.select_one(title_selector).text if title_selector else ""

          post_data = {'link': post_link, 'title': post_title}
          all_posts.append(post_data)

common_link_selector = 'a.post-link'
common_title_selector = 'h3.post-title'

all_posts = scrape_multiple_websites(website_urls, common_link_selector, common_title_selector)

for website, posts in all_posts.items():
    print(f"Website: {website}")
    for post in posts:
        print(f"Link: {post['link']}")
        print(f"Title: {post['title']}")
        print("\n")
```

The problem is that when I use the link selector it doesn't return anything because it doesn't find an anchor tag with the post-link attribute.

What should I use as a link selector?

Comment: Please edit and describe the problem that you encountered. You want to know if it is possible to scrape all websites. Yes, it is possible, but time consuming task. To shorten it, you should implement multitasking.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the post and described the problem. I am not really sure what you mean by multitasking in this scenario. @Jurakin

Comment: So you're looking for `link` and `title` of posts, but sometimes the attribute `link` of `a.post-link` in html doesn't exist, right? Can't you just use `soup.find_all("a.post-link", href=True, link=True)`? It would be clearer if you provided a web page where it doesn't work, so I can look at it.